# Upgrade Domain Controller SKU from Server 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

Our MS partner licenses unfortunately no longer include Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, so I am forced to upgrade all of our servers from Standard to Enterprise.

All have gone without a hitch until the DC, which needs upgrading from Standard to Enterprise.

How do I upgrade the SKU without demoting the server? Is there a way to activate the server using an Enterprise key?

Comment: Unless you are only running a single DC (in which case the lack of redundancy should be your priority) why not re-install on one and then the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "anytime upgrade" a machine from Server 2008 R2 Standard to Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, but only if it is *not* a domain controller:

http://architectevangelist.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/windows-server-2008-r2-anytime-upgrade/

However, standard Microsoft Windows Server [downgrade rights](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/downgrade-rights.aspx) should apply to your situation. These apply both to *older versions* and to *lower editions* of the same product. In other words, a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise license could be used to run Server 2003 Enterprise, or it could be used to run Server 2008 R2 Standard. Please check with your MS Licensing specialist if you have questions about how this may apply to your situation.